# ASP.NET TreeView control - CheckedNodes is always empty

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have an ASP.NET TreeView control with the "ShowCheckboxes" state set to "All".

If I check the boxes on the tree, then the tree.CheckedNodes property is always "False".
I've also tried looking at the individual Nodes(i).Checked property, but those are also all false.

If I manually set the Checked property to True from code, then it **does** get reflected in the .CheckedNodes property.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious- why would this simple boolean property fail to reflect what I've done in the UI?

```
  Protected Function GetChosenIDs() As List(Of Guid)
        Try
            Dim result As List(Of Guid) = New List(Of Guid)

            'This loop never executes, because nothing is marked "Checked".
            For Each node As TreeNode In tree.CheckedNodes
                result.Add(New Guid(node.Value))
            Next
            Return result
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: Can you post the ASPX code, please?

Comment: Are you using jQuery (or other client-side logic) which manipulates the DOM?  If so, make sure it hasn't moved your rendered TreeView HTML outside the <form> tags (for example, the default implementation of jqueryui.dialog does exactly that).  Anything outside the <from> is ignored by the ViewState, so changes to it won't make it back to the codebehind on form submission.